# Simple jquery box hide with rails 3 is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed the Jquery gem and made necessary changes for Jquery to work with rails 3.

I was trying to achieve a simple box fadeout effect when a link is clicked.

Here is my index.html.erb code :-

```
<div id ="box">
</div>
<%= link_to "Click Here", :remote => true%>
```

Here is my index.js.rjs code :-

```
$(function(){

$('a').click(function()
    {$('#box').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

However I am not able to get the desired effect. Any suggestion on where I am messing it up?

Thanks,

Comment: is id "box" a typo? Should be id="box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. It should be

```
id="box"
```

and

```
{$('#box').fadeOut();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNszJ/

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing the second issue will check if it works by making this change the first one was a typo :)

Comment: it is still not working I think there might be a problem with the way I am using rails convention

Comment: Also, in the JS debugger, can you check that your rjs is being rendered?

Comment: Actually I had to change the file format to .js.erb to make it work with Jquery .rjs format works with prototype. I am not sure how to use JS debugger

Comment: @ spike any suggestions how to overcome the problem I am facing?

Comment: In chrome or firebug, can you make sure that the javascript is loaded? The example I posted on jsfiddle should work. You could put this code in application.js since it doesnt need any erb features.

Comment: tested it in firebug and jquery.js file is getting loaded. I tried with the example which you have posted on jsfiddle but it was also not giving the desired effect could you please find the time to look at my application its at github : git@github.com:Akram-Khan/Fadeout.git

Comment: Jquery is loaded, but is your index.js.erb loaded? Can you try moving the code into your application.js file? Also, what about the link I posted isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: I copied the javascipt code into application.js file but still there is no change. index.js.erb was not getting loaded. I have used the code which you have posted on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I'm know nothing about ROR, but I think you don't need the function initializer at the beginning, so something like:

```
$('a').click(function() {$('#box').fadeOut(); });
```

Should suffice.

Comment: The jquery $() at the beginning makes the code run once the document is ready. see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

After struggling to get the answer with rails 3.0 we moved to rails 3.1 and SOLVED with the help of this post http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=45155

These are the steps:-

1) Upgrade to rails 3.1
2) Remove the # at the top of js file as these are ruby codes and the javascript wont compile.
3) Check in bugzilla if your javascript is loaded 
4) If  your javascript behaviour is upon pressing of a link or button make sure that the action does not generate a server request.

eg:- link_to "click here", :remote => true will call the javascript code and then reload the page therefore you wont see any javascript action

link_to "click here", "#", :remote => true will show you a proper javascript action

hope this helpful to others as well:)